# OSError when trying to register in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to submit 2 forms at a time to create my student user in Django. I have been struggling for a while now, but I think I'm finally closing to an end on how to manage 2 forms at a time for my users to register. But when I fill in the data from my view, I get the error:

```
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: "C:\\Users\\danny\\Desktop\\Projects\\bachelor_thesis\\eve\\templates\\{'form1': <UserForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(username;email;first_name;last_name;password)>, 'form2': <StudentForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(phone;student_ID;photo)>}"
```

Here are my files:

```
@csrf_protect
def student_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = UserForm(request.POST, prefix="user")
        form2 = StudentForm(request.POST, prefix="profile")
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            # create initial entry for user
            username = form1.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form1.cleaned_data["password"]
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, password)
            new_user.save()

            # create entry for UserProfile (extension of new_user object)
            profile = form2.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = new_user
            profile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("index")
    else:
        form1 = UserForm(prefix="user")
        form2 = StudentForm(prefix="profile")
    c = {
        'form1': form1,
        'form2': form2,
    }
    c.update(request)
    return render(request, "student_signup_form.html", c)
```

```css
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password')


class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('phone', 'student_ID', 'photo')
```

```html
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    student_ID = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=14,
                                  validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^.{14}$',
                                                             message='The ID needs to be 14 characters long.')])
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='students_images')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_student(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Student.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_student(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Also, when I open registration form, password is seeable. Also, how do I add a confirmation password fields? Thanks.
Here is the traceback: https://pastebin.com/b90muPZY
This issue is bothering me for a while.

Comment: Something very weird is happening here, it seems to be switching the template_name and context arguments - but you are passing them in the right order. Are you sure it is definitely running the code you have here? Could you have had them in the wrong order, run the code, then changed it without restarting the server?

Comment: For some reason, after restarting server, it worked. Also, I managed to add password and password confirmation field. But now I get error when I submit form: "This field is required." under the student IT field. Any idea about that sir ?